# How to invoke a CCColorLayer Class's method from another class(it extends Activity) method, Android?

Tags: android, methods, android-activity, cocos2d-android

i need to invoke a method of class A (it extends CCColorLayer) from a method of class B (it extends activity). How is it possible? Tried creating object for Class A in class B. But its not the solution. Each time its creating different layer. please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please post some code that shows what you are trying to do. Normally you would invoke a method of class A on an object of type A. So this means that you would have to create an instance of class A to operate on. Your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to create a singleton pattern??

```
 public Class A extends CCcolorlayer
    { 
    private static final A INSTANCE= new A();
     A() 
    { 
    }
     public static A getInstance() 
    { return INSTANCE; 
    } 

    }
```

From Class B

```
 public class B
{
   B()
     {
        A.getInstance();// which returns object of the class A.(you dont need to create object of class A everytime.)
     }

}
```

Im not sure whether you are looking for this.